# How to execute stored procedure in EF Core with return value TResult

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I created an async method with `TResult` return type but I get error in return value.

I try to return a list value but I'm getting an error:

```
public async Task<IList<T>> ExecWithStoreProcedureGetListAsync<T>(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
        query = "EXEC " + query + " ";

        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            var cItem = (SqlParameter)item;
            query = query + "@" + cItem.ParameterName + " " + (cItem.Direction == System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output ? "out" : "") + ",";
        }

        query = query.Substring(0, query.Length - 1);

        return await this.context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(query, parameters).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Error:

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no accessible extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

EF Core provides the following methods to execute a stored procedure:

1. DbSet.FromSql()
2. DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()

**Using FromSql**

This method executes the stored procedure which returns entity data

```
using (var context = new SampleContext())
{
 var authorId = new SqlParameter("@AuthorId", 1);
 var books = context.Books
    .FromSql("EXEC GetBooksByAuthor @AuthorId" , authorId)
    .ToList();
 }
```

**Using ExecuteSqlCommand()**

This method returns an integer specifying the number of rows affected by the SQL statement passed to it. Valid operations are **INSERT**, **UPDATE** and **DELETE**. The method is not used for returning entities

```
using(var context = new SampleContext())
{
   var name = new SqlParameter("@CategoryName", "Test");
   context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC AddCategory @CategoryName", name);
}
```

Reference :

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql#stored-procedures

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx